# Why does this Pair class not work as I expect

Tags: javascript

My background is C++ where it seems working with objects is very different to Javascript.  C++ has a Pair object like the Pair below I am trying to re-create.  But this class does not work as I intended.  Perhaps it is totally the wrong approach for Javascript.  My ultimate aim is to parse a string of key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3; into an associative array.  So any tips on that would be helpful.  But my first problem is the Pair class below.  any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>my title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Pair class - doesnt seem to work
function Pair(key, value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

Pair.prototype.Key = function() { return this.key; }
Pair.prototype.Value = function() { return this.value; }


function getValueAndKey(text, splitter) {
   //Pair pair = {};
   if(text) {
     var delim = typeof splitter !== 'undefined' ? splitter : '='; 
     var delimpos = text.indexOf(delim);
     if(delimpos != -1) {
          var strkey = text.substr(0, delimpos);
          var strvalue = text.substr(delimpos+1);
          return Pair(strkey, strvalue);      
     }      
   }
   return null;
}

function doIt() {

   function Options(sourceString) {
      this.source = sourceString;

      //populate key/value pairs from source string
      var vars_array = sourceString.split(";");
      for(var i = 0; i < vars_array.length; ++i) {
         //alert("adding vars_array[" + i + "] = " + vars_array[i]);
         var pair = getValueAndKey(vars_array[i]);
         if(pair)  //pair is ALWAYS undefined :(
            alert("key=" + pair.Key() + " value=" + pair.Value());       
      }
   }

   //exercise class
   var sourceString = "cat=Cookie;legs=4;favouritefood=lamb;type=Siamese;";
   var opts = new Options(sourceString);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="doIt();">
some test program
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need those prototype functions at all, and in getValueAndKey function you have to return new Pair(strkey, strvalue) instead of just Pair.
Maybe this solves your problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>my title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Pair class - doesnt seem to work
function Pair(key, value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

function getValueAndKey(text, splitter) {
   //Pair pair = {};
   if(text) {
     var delim = typeof splitter !== 'undefined' ? splitter : '='; 
     var delimpos = text.indexOf(delim);
     if(delimpos != -1) {
          var strkey = text.substr(0, delimpos);
          var strvalue = text.substr(delimpos+1);
          return new Pair(strkey, strvalue);      
     }      
   }
   return null;
}

function doIt() {

   function Options(sourceString) {
      this.source = sourceString;

      //populate key/value pairs from source string
      var vars_array = sourceString.split(";");
      for(var i = 0; i < vars_array.length; ++i) {
         //alert("adding vars_array[" + i + "] = " + vars_array[i]);
         var pair = getValueAndKey(vars_array[i]);
         if(pair)  //pair is ALWAYS undefined :(
            alert("key=" + pair.key + " value=" + pair.value);       
      }
   }

   //exercise class
   var sourceString = "cat=Cookie;legs=4;favouritefood=lamb;type=Siamese;";
   var opts = new Options(sourceString);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="doIt();">
some test program
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did to fix the issue?

Comment: Javascript is confusing because you can create an object without new.  Thanks. And just noticed your edit on the Pair members, thanks Again.

Comment: Yes you can but in your code return Pair(strkey, strvalue); did not create any new objects. The difference is that when you call it with the new keyword it creates a new Object, calls the function Pair on it (this will point to the new Object) and in the end it returns it.

Comment: @user619818 You can create an object in C++ without new too. Lets say I have a class `Derek`, I can create a new `Derek` by just typing `Derek me(random, constructor_options);`. I don't have to do `me = new Derek(random, constructor_options);`